# Save Images inline (Base64) for Markdown export in Jupyter notebook

Tags: base64, markdown, jupyter

How can images from Matplotlib:

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('Image.png', facecolor='w', edgecolor='w', transparent=False, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.1)
plt.show()
```

saved inline (embedded as base64?), so that there is no need for external files,
when the Notebook is downloaded as a Markdown file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My workaround solution:

install this: https://github.com/freeman-lab/embed-images
and this: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

add to the first cell:

```
%matplotlib inline
import os 
import ipyparams
```

and to the last cell:

```
os.system('jupyter nbconvert --to markdown ' + ipyparams.notebook_name)
os.system('embed-images ' + ipyparams.notebook_name[:-6] + '.md > ' + ipyparams.notebook_name[:-6] + '_emb.md')
```

NBconvert convert the *notebook.ipynb* to *notebook.md* with all images in the folder *notebook_files*.
Embed-Images convert these images to base64, insert their code in the file and saves it as *notebook_emb.md*

Both lines outputs "0" for a successfully conversion.

Comment: After restarting the kernel, there will be no output .md files, you have to run the last cell again!